# List comprehensions in python nested loops

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, nested, list-comprehension

```
scrabble_scores = [(1, "EAOINRTLSU"), (2, "DG"), (3, "BCMP"),
               (4, "FHVWY"), (5, "K"), (8, "JX"), (10, "QZ")]
def get_scrabble_scorer():
    print {x:y for x,z in scrabble_scores for y in z}
    pass

get_scrabble_scorer()
```

I expected an output :

```
[1:'E',1:'A,1:'O',1:'I'....]
```

such that score will be mapped to each alphabet in the word
But i got the output :

```
{1: 'U', 2: 'G', 3: 'P', 4: 'Y', 5: 'K', 8: 'X', 10: 'Z'}
```

Help me

Comment: You can't get `1:'E',1:'A'` . Keys of a dictionary should be unique.

Comment: if you switch `x` and `y `in your dictionary it should work, ie: `print {y:x for x,z in scrabble_scores for y in z}`

Comment: `{"A": 1, "B": 3, "C": 3, "D": 2, "E": 1, "F": 4, "G": 2, "H": 4, "I": 1, "J": 8, "K": 5, "L": 1, "M": 3, "N": 1, "O": 1, "P": 3, "Q": 10, "R": 1, "S": 1, "T": 1, "U": 1, "V": 4, "W": 4, "X": 8, "Y": 4, "Z": 10}`

Comment: Why not use the characters as keys instead? Seems like for scrabble you'd need to look up scores from letters more often than letters from scores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic in your list comprehension is fine.  You can verify this by changing

```
print {x:y for x,z in scrabble_scores for y in z}
```

to

```
print [(x,y) for x,z in scrabble_scores for y in z]
```

which prints out

```
[(1, 'E'), (1, 'A'), (1, 'O'), (1, 'I'), (1, 'N'), (1, 'R'), (1, 'T'), (1, 'L'), (1, 'S'), (1, 'U'), (2, 'D'), (2, 'G'), (3, 'B'), (3, 'C'), (3, 'M'), (3, 'P'), (4, 'F'), (4, 'H'), (4, 'V'), (4, 'W'), (4, 'Y'), (5, 'K'), (8, 'J'), (8, 'X'), (10, 'Q'), (10, 'Z')]
```

The reason why your implementation doesn't work is because each key of the dictionary must be unique.  Therefore, when you're setting `1:A`, the previous `key:value` pair of `1:E` is overwritten.

Maybe you're looking for the letter to be the key?  If so, then just swap x and y:

```
print {y:x for x,z in scrabble_scores for y in z}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change the line with the print command to:

```
print [{x:y} for x,z in scrabble_scores for y in z]
```

Then the output will be:

```
[{1: 'E'}, {1: 'A'}, {1: 'O'}, {1: 'I'}...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not insist on the keys being the numbers use:

```
>>> {y:x for x,z in scrabble_scores for y in z}
{'E': 1, 'M': 3, 'F': 4, 'Z': 10, 'G': 2, 'Q': 10, 'U': 1, 'R': 1, 'I': 1, 'C': 3, 'A': 1, 'K': 5, 'Y': 4, 'L': 1, 'B': 3, 'O': 1, 'D': 2, 'T': 1, 'W': 4, 'S': 1, 'X': 8, 'P': 3, 'H': 4, 'J': 8, 'V': 4, 'N': 1}
```

You can use it to calculate the score of a word:

```
>>> score_mapping = {y:x for x,z in scrabble_scores for y in z}

>>> word = 'Hello'
>>> sum(score_mapping[letter.upper()] for letter in word)
8
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch the dictionary, so the keys are the letters and the values are the scores.  Dictionaries in Python cannot have duplicate keys.

This is also how you will calculate the score of a word, by looking up each letter (not by looking up each number).

```
>>> {letter:score for score,letters in scrabble_scores for letter in letters}
{'A': 1, 'C': 3, 'B': 3, 'E': 1, 'D': 2, 'G': 2, 'F': 4, 'I': 1, 'H': 4, 'K': 5,
 'J': 8, 'M': 3, 'L': 1, 'O': 1, 'N': 1, 'Q': 10, 'P': 3, 'S': 1, 'R': 1, 'U': 1
, 'T': 1, 'W': 4, 'V': 4, 'Y': 4, 'X': 8, 'Z': 10}
```

Here is how you would use the above mapping:

```
>>> word = 'hello'
>>> score = sum(lookup.get(i.upper(),0) for i in word)
>>> score
8
```

Comment: Thanks @BurhanKhalid. But what is the difference between having `{x:y..` and `{y:x..`

Comment: The keys are the letters (which aren't repeated) and the values are the values for each letter. Python dictionaries cannot have duplicate keys, you cannot have `{3: 'C', 3: 'B'}`.